# how to deploy quote templates in salesforce, I think we can't deploy using changesets? Is there any alternate ways to deploy?

Tags: deployment, change-set, cpq

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000irFdAAI

Could you please share your thoughts on this, with out manual creation any other possibilities to deploy quote templates

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QuoteTemplates are an unsupported metadata type in the Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm?search_text=unsupported). As such, Changesets, ant scripts, devops tools, and sfdx can't deploy them

As you've seen in this [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KhbEAAS), SFDC Product Management said it had reached the pain point 4 years ago; then radio silence.

As such, SFDC guidance is:

> The following components can’t be retrieved or deployed with Metadata
> API, and changes to them must be made manually in each of your
> organizations
>
> ...
> Quote Templates

You could move to CPQ and then deploy the templates using Data Loader or a DevOps Data Deploy tool such as Gearset and others.

Answer (score 1):

The quote templates fall under metadata components that need to be manually created in Salesforce orgs and there is no workaround as of now.

The link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm is currently not working. You can see external [link](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/metadata-components-that-needs-to-be-deployed-manually-in-salesforce/) that mentions the same.